# Magento 1.11.1 EE cli-install crashes - Mage/Reports duplicate install script

Tags: magento

I'm trying to install Magento 1.11.1 EE from command line.
The installation crashes at some point throwing the following error:

```
ERROR: Error in file: "/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/data/reports_setup/data-install-1.6.0.0.php"
A page URL key for specified store already exists.
```

Looking at the source code I found that there are 3 scripts that are doing the same thing:

/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/sql/reports_setup/mysql4-install-0.7.1.php (initial script)
/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/sql/reports_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.0-0.7.1.php ( ??? basically doing the same thing as the one above but with DROP TABLE IF EXISTS)
**/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/data/reports_setup/data-install-1.6.0.0.php**

The fix for this would be to remove (by patch of course) one of the scripts (preferably the last one) but I'm trying to understand if this is something that should be there or just a stupid mistake.

You can refere at the link below if you don't have the code opened: 
http://www.magentodocs.org/1.7.0.2/d5/dde/_reports_2data_2reports__setup_2data-install-1_86_80_80_8php_source.php

Comment: There was another install script that was being executed in the local code pool.

Comment: But still, there is a bit strange that the install script from the Mage_Reports module is not located in the sql directory, where, btw there are also two similar scripts.